# How do I export calendar events in Mozilla lightning

Tags: thunderbird, export, lightning

How do I export calendar events in Mozilla Lightning?

I'm using Thunderbird 3.0.4.

(Sorry for such a basic question, but clicking on "Help contents" takes me to http://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/kb/ , and searching the knowledge base for lightning export got zero hits, and searching for export only got one irrelevant hit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it ... it was under "Events and Tasks".

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this exports the **entire calendar** and not just one event.  I'm still searching for a method to export a single event in TB/Lightning 17.0.

Answer (score 15):

To export selected events from Thunderbird (not whole calendars):

1. Select the events to export in the calendar view (multi-selection using `Ctrl`)
2. Hit `Ctrl`+`C`
3. Create a new text file in a text editor
4. `Ctrl`+`V` there
5. Save the file with ending `.ics`

Comment: For real? Thunderbird does not have the ability to export single events with one click into files or even its own emails? I am afraid I will have to give you a +1.

Answer (score 2):

Cool. 12 years later this still works:

- copy event from thunderbird
- paste in text-editor
- save as .ics
- doubleclick .ics file

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150066)

Answer (score 0):

this tip helped me a lot : https://superuser.com/a/1632510/1759195

I was looking on the mozilla website and neither has this explanation or I didn't find it

Comment: Hint - you could improve your answer by adding the summary to your answer.  Link only answers tend to get deleted by the bot.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1163858)